# Properly using multiple resources with Rx

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

I need to use multiple disposable resources with Rx. This is how I have nested the `Observable.Using` statements (the inner source is just for testing).

```cs
var obs = Observable.Using(
    () => new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.Open),
    fs => Observable.Using(
        () => new StreamReader(fs),
        sr => Observable.Create<string>(o =>
            TaskPoolScheduler.Default.ScheduleAsync(async (sch, ct) =>
            {
                while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    var s = await sr.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    if (s is null) break;

                    o.OnNext(s);
                }
                o.OnCompleted();
            }))));

obs.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

Is there a more concise way to `use` multiple disposable resources?

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of a general way to `use` unlimited number of resources, but at least you could make helper methods for the common cases of 2-3 resources. Here is an implementation for two:

```
public static IObservable<TResult> Using<TResult, TResource1, TResource2>(
    Func<TResource1> resourceFactory1,
    Func<TResource1, TResource2> resourceFactory2,
    Func<TResource1, TResource2, IObservable<TResult>> observableFactory)
    where TResource1 : IDisposable
    where TResource2 : IDisposable
{
    return Observable.Using(resourceFactory1, resource1 => Observable.Using(
        () => resourceFactory2(resource1),
        resource2 => observableFactory(resource1, resource2)));
}
```

Usage example:

```
var obs = Using(
    () => new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.Open),
    (fs) => new StreamReader(fs),
    (fs, sr) => Observable.Create<string>(o =>
        TaskPoolScheduler.Default.ScheduleAsync(async (sch, ct) =>
        {
            while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var s = await sr.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (s is null) break;

                o.OnNext(s);
            }
            o.OnCompleted();
        })));
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually when I have a set of resources to be used in a cold observable, I stick with the create pattern which is much easier to read.

```
var obs = Observable.Create<string>(observer =>
{

    var fs = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.Open);
    var sr = new StreamReader(fs);
    var task = TaskPoolScheduler.Default.ScheduleAsync(async (_, ct) =>
    {
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var s = await sr.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (s is null) break;

            observer.OnNext(s);
        }
        observer.OnCompleted();
    });


    return new CompositeDisposable(task, fs, sr);
});
```

Comment: Will this work if a subscriber neglects to dispose the subscription? Or in that case the resources will remain undisposed?

Comment: When it completes, it will auto-detach and dispose.

Comment: You can test this by adding a `Disposable.Create(() => Console.WriteLine("Done!"))` to the list.

Comment: Yes, observables will automatically dispose of all subscriptions when they error or complete.

Comment: While this is way more readable it has an issue when any of the lines after the creation of a disposable resource throw: Normally, with a `using` statement it would properly dispose the resource, but in this case that won't happen. As the returned disposable object is not created in that case either, the resource is not properly disposed.

Comment: None of the lines after it will throw though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just continue to use the double `Using` pattern, but I'd clean up the internals of how you're reading the lines. Try this:

```
var obs =
    Observable.Using(() => new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.Open),
        fs => Observable.Using(() => new StreamReader(fs),
            sr =>
                Observable
                    .Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync(() => sr.ReadLineAsync()))
                    .Repeat()
                    .TakeWhile(x => x != null)));
```

You should try to avoid `Observable.Create` where possible.

Cleaner observable queries means that the `Using` operators don't look so out-of-place.